# Array printing out multiple characters in basic dungeon crawler

Tags: c++, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

My name is Eric, and I ran into a problem while programming a basic "dungeon crawler" using c++.

The problem is that when the player moves certain spaces to the left or right, there is another player character generated so that there is two on the screen instead of one.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>


using namespace std;



const int columns = 7, rows = 10;
string gridArray[rows][columns];
bool xIsGenerated = false;
bool gISGenerated = false;

int playerX = 0, playerY = 0;


void displayGrid(int rows, int columns){

    for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++){
        for(int x = 0; x < rows; x++){
            cout << gridArray[i][x];
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << gISGenerated << endl;
    return;
}

void generatePieces(int rows, int columns){

    int tcount = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int x = 0; x < columns; x++){

            srand(time(NULL) + x + i);



            int r = rand() % 5;

            if(r == 1 && tcount < 4){
                gridArray[i][x] = "T ";
                tcount++;
            }else if(r == 2 && !xIsGenerated){
                gridArray[i][x] = "X ";
                xIsGenerated = true;
            }


        }
    }

    if(!xIsGenerated){
        srand(time(NULL)*3);

        int r = rand() % rows+1;
        int c = rand() % columns+1;

        gridArray[r][c] = "X ";
        xIsGenerated = true;

    }

    return;
}

void generatePlayer(int rows, int columns){

    if(!gISGenerated){
        srand(time(NULL)*3);

        int r = rand() % rows+1;
        int c = rand() % columns+1;

        gridArray[r][c] = "G ";
        playerX = r;
        playerY = c;
        gISGenerated = true;

    }
}

void initGrid(int rows, int columns){

    for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++){
        for(int x = 0; x < rows; x++){
            gridArray[i][x] = ". ";
        }
    }


    generatePieces(rows, columns);
    generatePlayer(rows, columns);

    return;
}

//i is the rows
//x is the columns


void movePlayer(){
    char input = 'x';

    cin >> input;


    if(input == 'w' && playerX != 0){
        gridArray[playerX][playerY] = ". ";
        gridArray[playerX-1][playerY] = "G ";
        playerX--;
    }

    if(input == 's' && playerX != 6){
        gridArray[playerX][playerY] = ". ";
        gridArray[playerX+1][playerY] = "G ";
        playerX++;
    }

    if(input == 'a' && playerY != 0){
        gridArray[playerX][playerY] = ". ";
        gridArray[playerX][playerY-1] = "G ";
        playerY--;
    }

    if(input == 'd' && playerY != 9){
        gridArray[playerX][playerY] = ". ";
        gridArray[playerX][playerY+1] = "G ";
        playerY++;
    }



    system("CLS");

    displayGrid(rows, columns);
    cout << playerX << ": " << playerY << endl;
}

void firstTime(){
    displayGrid(rows, columns);
    cout << playerX << ": " << playerY << endl;
    return;
}



int main()
{
    initGrid(rows,columns);
    firstTime();

    while(true){
        movePlayer();
    }


    return 0;
 }
```

Quick explanation of code:

A multidimensional array will serve as the graphic for displaying what is going on. This array starting with the function "initGrid" will print out ". " strings in the array and on the screen

The Generate Pieces function takes that array filled with ". " strings, and using a random number generator, it places "T " strings and 1 "X " string. This "X " will be the goal while the T's will be traps that kill the player.

Generate Player does the same thing, but instead places only 1 "G " string. This is the player.

After initGrid is called, then inside of the main function is the "firstTime" function, nothing complex, just displays data to the screen.

Then lastly, I have a while loop that calls the function "movePlayer", using the same array, based on what the user inputs, it will move the "G " string accordingly and replace the last location of the g string with an empty ". " string.

I have tried to return the location of the second G string and once I did that I tried to replace it with a ". " string, but it failed as the code didn't remove the second one, and once the second one was out of the array (the second g character moves corresponding to the first g character) the first G character got removed.

I am drawing a blank here as to what I should do next, it seemed to be a simple problem at first, but it is giving me a run for it's money.

Thanks for reading, and I hope to get an answer soon to my problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have a look at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the section on [minimal complete examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Try to whittle your code down to the simplest example that shows the bug -- this isn't just for our convenience, it's a vital skill and you might discover the bug on your own along the way. In particular, try to remove the randomness, so that we can have a *reproducible* example.

Comment: I really don't think you want to: `srand(time(NULL) + x + i); ` because what you have is not really random. It's going to be something very heavily biassed by `x` and `i`. `srand` is best used once very early in the program to set up `rand` and then left alone unless you are generating a large number of random numbers. And in that case, [take a look at `std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) for better results.

Comment: In addition to getting rows and columns mixed up, you have hard-coded limits like `if(input == 'd' && playerY != 9)...`. You can avoid snags like this by developing new functionality *in isolation.* Get the movement and the obstacle placement right *separately*, before you try to combine them. Until you have them right, don't attempt random placement, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code with [asan](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) and [ubsan](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html) which told me you have an out of bounds access in line 23 `cout << gridArray[i][x];` where you access `gridArray[8]` which doesn't exist.

Looks like you mixed up rows and columns. I recommend you use sanitizers too.